# mongoose and nodeJs for update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, constructor, findoneandupdate

i am new to nodejs and mongoDB

i am developing a project in to it i need to calculate rating on product for this i've done
in to model

```
    ReviewSchema.statics.calculateAverage = async function (productId) {
          console.log("in to calculate rating " + productId);
          const result = await this.aggregate([
            { $match: { product: productId } },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                avgRating: { $avg: "$rating" },
                numberOfRating: { $sum: 1 },
              },
            },
          ]);
          // this.model('Product').findOneAndUpdate({_id:productId});
          console.log("resulr...." + result[0].avgRating);
        
          await this.model("Product").findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: productId },
            {
              // averageRating: Math.ceil(result[0]?.avgRating || 0),//working but want fraction
              averageRating: result[0]?.avgRating || 0,
              numOfReviews: result[0]?.numberOfRating || 0,
            }
          );
        };
        
        //for save
        ReviewSchema.post("save", async function () {
          await this.constructor.calculateAverage(this.product);
        });
//for remove
        ReviewSchema.post("remove", async function () {
      await this.constructor.calculateAverage(this.product);
    });
```

this works ok on saving or removing review i.e calculation of review working perfectly
Now, my query is when user update review i want to recalculate the reviews
for that i've done

```
ReviewSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function () {
  console.log("test....update");

  await this.constructor.calculateAverage(this.product);// this line gives me this.constructor.calculateAverage is not a function
 
});
```

but for update it gives me **this.constructor.calculateAverage is not a function**

please help me to solve this issue

(for update if i do use save() then works ok but i want solution with findOneAndUpdate if it possible please guide me )

Comment: Maybe your function name `ReviewSchema.statics.calculateAverage` has something to do with the error.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: TypeError: this.constructor.calculateAverage is not a function
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (H:\node_work\E-Commerce-API\models\review_model.js:71:26)
    at next (H:\node_work\E-Commerce-API\node_modules\kareem\index.js:238:35)
    at Kareem.execPost (H:\node_work\E-Commerce-API\node_modules\kareem\index.js:266:3)
    at _cb (H:\node_work\E-Commerce-API\node_modules\kareem\index.js:367:15)
    at H:\node_work\E-Commerce-API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3254:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)